# Angular accessing $scope objects with dynamic names

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angular controller whereby I'm trying to look through a list of strings, querying an ajax query for each string within the list. The code is as follows:

```
var itemsliststrings = ["department", "year", "project", "subdepartment"];

itemsliststrings.forEach(function (itemStr) {
    $http.post("/Budget/GetListBudget", { budgetType: itemStr })
    .success(function (data) {
        var the_string = itemStr;
        var model = $parse(the_string);
        model.assign($scope, data);
        $scope.$apply();
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        toastr.error('An error occured, unable to load ' + itemStr);
    });
});
```

This  is the code that doesn't work. it complains with the error `'$parse' is undefined`. I took this example from a SO post.

I basically want to be able to loop through my itemsliststrings, post the string to an web method, and set the return data for this to a model variable called that particular string. So when I take the "department" string, I submit this string to the web method, I get a data object back, which I then set to the $scope.department object.

Thanks

Comment: Why not do `$scope.values[itemStr] = value`?

Comment: I receive the error `Unable to set property 'department' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: You would need to define the `$scope.values` object first: `$scope.values = {}`.

Comment: Hello, I tried this and it no longer errors, the data gets set into the model, however the view does not update once the data is set, how do I make the view update to the new model data?

Comment: How are you referencing the scoped property in the html?

Comment: `<select ng-model="departmentsel" ng-options="dp.display for dp in departments"><option value=""> - </option></select>`

Comment: Never mind, silly question, I caned the ng-options to reference `"values.department"` and it correctly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you inject the $parse provider in your controller?

```
    .controller('yourController',function($scope,$parse,etc..){});
```

Comment: Doh! No I didn't, I have added the $parse provider now and it successfully parses the variable name. I know this is another question within a question, but once I call the `$scope.$apply()` method, an error appears: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest ` Any ideas what this might mean? My view does no update with the correct values because of this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just $scope[itemStr] = data?